# How to fade smoothly between gradients in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This code populates a div with a predefined set of gradients and fades through them in a cycle using jQuery's .animate() method:

```js
/// Background Gradient Cycler
var gradients = [
  ['#9eb5d7', '#242424'],
  ['#efe2ae', '#a8acc9'],
  ['#6f7554', '#eee1ad']
]
var gradientsRev = gradients.reverse()
var gradientCover = document.getElementById('gradientCover');
for (var g = 0; g < gradientsRev.length; g++) {
  var gradEl = document.createElement('div')
  gradEl.className = 'gradient'
  gradEl.style.background = `linear-gradient(${gradientsRev[g][0]}, ${gradientsRev[g][1]})`;
  gradientCover.appendChild(gradEl)
}
var gradientEls = document.querySelectorAll('#gradientCover .gradient')

function gradientCycler() {
  function gradeFade(i, opDest) {
    var fadeDur = 20000
    $(gradientEls[i]).animate({
      'opacity': opDest
    }, {
      duration: fadeDur,
      complete: function() {
        if (parseInt(i) > 1) {
          if (parseInt(opDest) === 0) gradeFade(i - 1, 0)
          else gradFadeStart()
        } else {
          gradeFade(gradientEls.length - 1, 1)
        }
      }
    })
  }
  var gradFadeStart = function() {
    $('.gradient').css('opacity', 1);
    gradeFade(gradientEls.length - 1, 0)
  }
  gradFadeStart()
}
gradientCycler()
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gradientCover,
.gradient {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div id="gradientCover"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the transition at certain parts is visibly choppy, with banding artifacts --

[image]

What can be done to reduce this artifacting so that the transition between the gradients appears smoother and less choppy?

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can see that actual code working, not an image of it. The issue with the banding is likely due to the colour depth of your monitor, though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan updated with full html. I see, so in that case would there be any way to improve it across monitors with different colour depths?

Comment: looks fine for me, probably it's your monitor fault

Comment: There is probably not much you can do about that. Banding could occur due to various reasons (gpu-driver, the display itself, os, …). The colors emitted by the browser are likely to be correct. And some of the perceived banding effects can just be an optical illusion.

Comment: Although it's looking fine for me (on a reasonably modern/powerful laptop Windows10) I notice that it take up a lot of the GPU - around 80% on occasion. A less powerful system might struggle to keep up with the animation.

Comment: I have the same performance issue as @AHaworth, and I'm not on a slow PC. I'd strongly suggest you move any heavy UI rendering logic to CSS, which can be done like this: https://codepen.io/P1N2O/pen/pyBNzX.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'll take a look at that, thanks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 's linked code reduces the GPU load down to around half the original code so definitely worth looking into - still a bit of a potential battery-flattener though if run continuously as a background.

Comment: Strangely enough utilizing CSS animations is producing the worst banding distortion on my end. I managed to improve the performance quite a bit by pre-rendering PNGs with the HTML canvas' .toDataURL() method and animating through them in jQuery, but even that doesn't resolve the problem completely. About the same performance using Three.js. If it helps anyone I created a Codepen collection of all my tests: https://codepen.io/collection/zxBbgK

Answer (score 1):

I think is related to [color depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth), As a former CG artist I have seen these "artefacts" in software like Maya and Photoshop, to solve the problem it was necessary to increase the number of bits per channel ([in Photoshop going from 8 Bits/Channel to 16](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/bit-depth.html)).

Normally, this issue of bands appears when the two colors of the gradient are close **(in term of RGB values)** because there are few values of colors available between these two colors

If the gradient is rendered OR displayed (due to the monitor limitation) at a low number of bits per channel these banding effect can appear.

You can check your [monitor color depth here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_screen_colordepth).

You can also apply CSS according to this value:

```js
if (screen.colorDepth <= 8)
  //simple blue background color for 8 bit screens
  document.body.style.background = "#0000FF"
else
  //fancy blue background color for modern screens
  document.body.style.background = "#87CEFA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Including my codepen tests here as an answer just in case it helps anyone. I managed to get some improved performance by pre-rendering PNGs with the canvas' `.toDataURL()` method and animating through them in jQuery (also achieved about the same performance with this method but using Three.js):

https://codepen.io/tv/zxBbgK

Here's a working example of the JQuery method:

```js
/// Background Gradient Cycler
var gradients = [
  ['#9eb5d7', '#242424'],
  ['#efe2ae', '#a8acc9'],
  ['#6f7554', '#eee1ad']
]
var gradientsRev = gradients.reverse()
var gradientCover = document.getElementById('gradientCover');
for (var g = 0; g < gradientsRev.length; g++) {
  var gradEl = document.createElement('div')
  gradEl.className = 'gradient'
  var gradCanv = document.createElement('canvas')
  gradCanv.className = 'gradient'
  var ctx = gradCanv.getContext("2d");
  var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, gradCanv.height); 
  grd.addColorStop(0, gradients[g][0]);
  grd.addColorStop(1, gradients[g][1]);
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, gradCanv.width, gradCanv.height);
  var gradIm = gradCanv.toDataURL("img/png")
  gradEl.style.backgroundImage = `url(${gradIm})`
  gradientCover.appendChild(gradEl)
}
var gradientEls = document.querySelectorAll('#gradientCover .gradient')

function gradientCycler() {
  function gradeFade(i, opDest) {
    var fadeDur = 20000
    $(gradientEls[i]).animate({
      'opacity': opDest
    }, {
      duration: fadeDur,
      complete: function() {
        if (parseInt(i) > 1) {
          if (parseInt(opDest) === 0) gradeFade(i - 1, 0)
          else gradFadeStart()
        } else {
          gradeFade(gradientEls.length - 1, 1)
        }
      }
    })
  }
  var gradFadeStart = function() {
    $('.gradient').css('opacity', 1);
    gradeFade(gradientEls.length - 1, 0)
  }
  gradFadeStart()
}
gradientCycler()
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gradientCover,
.gradient {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div id="gradientCover"></div>
</div>
```